# Fill the Bucket

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Your task is to fill the bucket with numbers upto a given input.

#### Rules

Numbers occupy the leftmost position then rightmost, then leftmost and so on.

After overflow, the numbers start to gather around the bucket in a similar manner. They occupy position diagonally.

The examples should make it clear what the expected output is (Some rules are mentioned in the examples).

For more then 10, use the rightmost digit

#### Examples:

```
The bucket: 
|      |  or |      | 
|      |     |      | 
|      |     |      |
|      |     |      |
|------|     |______|

input:1  (You can start from either 0 or 1)
output:
|      |  (There can be whitespace to the left even if there is no overflow
|      |  but the bucket must not be distorted.)
|      |
|1     |
|------|

input:6
output:
|      |
|      |
|      |
|135642|
|------|

input:8
output:
|      |
|      |
|7    8|
|135642|
|------|

input:23
output:
|913 20|
|357864|
|791208|
|135642|
|------|

input:27
output:
  |913420|
  |357864|
  |791208|
  |135642|
75|------|6

input:30
output:
  |913420|
  |357864|
  |791208|
 9|135642|0
75|------|68

input:40
output:
    |913420|
    |357864|
   5|791208|6
 939|135642|040
7175|------|6828

input:54   (Maximum input for start=1)
    3|913420|4
   13|357864|42
  915|791208|620
 7939|135642|0408
57175|------|68286
```

This is **code-golf** so shortest code wins.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by _"you can start from either 0 or 1"_? May the sequence of digits itself be 0-indexed (i.e. `|024531|` for \$n=6\$) or only the input?

Comment: @Arnauld, yes, the sequence may start from 0

Comment: This is one of the better coding challenges for code golf that I have seen here!

Answer (score 9):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org),  <s>145</s>  143 bytes

A hard-coded pattern (see [**here**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177385/58563) for more maths).

1-indexed.

```javascript
n=>`    g|EGIJHF|h
   e]|?ACDB@|^f
  c[U|9;=><:|V\\d
 aYSO|357864|PTZb
_WQMK|------|LNRX\``.replace(/[3-h]/g,c=>(x=Buffer(c)[0])<n+51?x%10:' ')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcdbT4MwGIDhe35FL2bWxsJgwDa3lel0np3nI6CtXQsaUhamZsk@fzsSn6v3/RQ/YiWrj@WXbcqFqjWrDYs4amQwOzo5PT6E3GpOpTDZ2z@Y7sKrbl7G97AzYtF4CA9JsrCQeL69BD/sD3oBXN29vFtvj9cXZ2D/g/P5zVPCuVOpZSGkwp3Yt/O0k1HJIrxm02@tVYUlid2UjM126E3WW547bKM2qUexR3t0QLs@7fap79LApWGQWo4uq5mQOTaIRUiWZlUWyinKDPM5a23Mb2JaG40NaYITUv8B)

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @tsh*

Comment: `/[^\s|-]/` -> `/[0-z]/`

Comment: @tsh D'oh! I totally missed this simplification. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>144 ... 139</s>  137 bytes

A mathematical approach (see [**here**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177369/58563) for less maths).

0-indexed.

```javascript
n=>(y=4,g=x=>~y?(X=x>8?17-x:x,k=X<y?g:X<5?24-(z=4+y-X)*~z+y*2:y*6+X*2-18,~X?X^5?k<0?'-':(k+=x>8)<n?k%10:' ':'|':`
`)+g(~X?-~x:!y--):'')()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxNb4IwGADgu78CE5e29K2BWpR0vPS0685N9hEIE7Zh2kWXpdXJX2fz/uT5bH/aU3f8@PoWzr/t5x5nhzWNqGDAgPUUDbUY6tLkOxF0gBFtFc2gbVUYqQQ9o@JRWJZOZx5TqWO65TaVIi9hssa@FmasMkME0XTkt4hVzox3eaZJQjT5JbpZNIwP9F@LKehlFIJpQhhl8/1TDlsoQW5A7mCTgcqgUC@Lde@PD233Tl2CddJ5d/KH/frgB9o84urirs9udempY9eGsfkP)

#### How?

The output is built character by character, with \$y\$ decreasing from \$4\$ to \$0\$ and \$x\$ increasing from \$0\$ to \$18\$ on each row.

We define:

$$X=\begin{cases}x&\text{if }x\le 8\\17-x&\text{if }x>8\end{cases}$$

By writing the full values rather than just the unit digits, we get the following table:

```
 x |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 |  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
 X |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 |  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0 -1
---+----------------------------+-------------------------------
 4 | .. .. .. .. 52 || 18 20 22 | 23 21 19 || 53 .. .. .. .. \n
 3 | .. .. .. 50 42 || 12 14 16 | 17 15 13 || 43 51 .. .. .. \n
 2 | .. .. 48 40 34 || 6  8  10 | 11 9  7  || 35 41 49 .. .. \n
 1 | .. 46 38 32 28 || 0  2  4  | 5  3  1  || 29 33 39 47 .. \n
 0 | 44 36 30 26 24 || -- -- -- | -- -- -- || 25 27 31 37 45 \n
```

This table is essentially symmetric across the y-axis, except that the values on the left side are even and the values on the right side are their odd counterparts.

We define:

$$k=\begin{cases}24+(4+y-X)(5+y-X)+2y&\text{if }X<5\\6y+2X-18&\text{if }X>5\end{cases}$$

$$k'=\begin{cases}k&\text{if }x\le 8\\k+1&\text{if }x>8\end{cases}$$

And for each cell, we append:

- a linefeed if \$X=-1\$
- a pipe if \$X=5\$
- a hyphen if \$k<0\$
- a space if \$X<y\$ or \$k'>n\$ (where \$n\$ is the input)
- \$k' \bmod 10\$ otherwise

#### Commented

```javascript
n => (                                // main function taking n
  y = 4,                              // start with y = 4
  g = x =>                            // g = recursive function taking x
    ~y ?                              // if y is not equal to -1:
      ( X = x > 8 ? 17 - x : x,       //   compute X
        k = X < y ?                   //   if X is less than y:
          g                           //     set k to a non-numeric value
        :                             //   else:
          X < 5 ?                     //     if X is less than 5:
            24 - (z = 4 + y - X) * ~z //       apply the 'side numbers' formula
             + y * 2                  //
          :                           //     else:
            y * 6 + X * 2 - 18,       //       apply the 'middle numbers' formula
        ~X ?                          //   if X is not equal to -1:
          X ^ 5 ?                     //     if X is not equal to 5:
            k < 0 ?                   //       if k is less than 0:
              '-'                     //         append a hyphen
            :                         //       else:
              (k += x > 8) < n ?      //         update k to k'; if it's less than n:
                k % 10                //           append the unit digit of k'
              :                       //         else:
                ' '                   //           append a space
          :                           //     else (X = 5):
            '|'                       //       append a pipe
        :                             //   else (X = -1):
          `\n`                        //     append a linefeed
      )                               //
      + g(~X ? -~x : !y--)            //   update x and y, and do a recursive call
    :                                 // else (y = -1):
      ''                              //   stop recursion
)()                                   // initial call to g with x undefined
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 170 bytes

```python
I=input()
s="    u|SUWXVT|v\n   sk|MOQRPN|lt\n  qic|GIKLJH|djr\n oga]|ACEFDB|^bhp\nme_[Y|------|Z\`fn"
i=1
exec"s=s.replace(chr(64+i),[`i%10`,' '][i>I]);i+=1;"*55
print s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HchrD4FQHIDx932K1mYVMRne2LG5y/1@q4gcOuQ4OjG2/3dP/N49D/uE3p3moshAhLJnqKgCR5IYe8J0vlwtZvCyaJz8Cv3heDIagB/@xoO40DK6vU4bjpcgPvfz3oZKrdGsV2F78JhFb3hnriH9BxvLOVFJIEgX8Bu7Ekc8E2Dm712suF6gFPMpomqmQxJ61tFkUbZNUjZstURSSC9JyUJBYAGhocijSM99AQ)

Answer (score 3):

## Java 10, 168 bytes

```java
n->"    g|EGIJHF|h\n   e]|?ACDB@|^f\n  c[U|9;=><:|V\\d\n aYSO|357864|PTZb\n_WQMK|------|LNRX`".chars().forEach(c->System.out.print(c<46|c==124?(char)c:c<n+51?c%10:" "))
```

Port of [*@Arnauld*'s JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177369/52210) (so also 1-indexed, and outputting `-` as bottom). If you like this answer, make sure to upvote him as well!

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jZJbb4JAEIXf/RUTkiZLGojIRasCvWmv2gu9i23XERSrqwE0abr@drpYnvrEPkwyZ7@dPSeZGd1QZTb@ynBOkwR6NGI/FYCIpUEcUgygn7cAm2U0BiRCBya3hLStiJKkNI0Q@sDAhowpjpSzE945u7g87/Kpz0QbDLl7dHJ6fMjfw1zAwSM/aNlOu8mffH8sJPrq3XDdrDcsg98@vI189vF817viyu7w6/79y6ek4pTGCZHVcBl3KE4JKo73naTBQl2uU3UVC28E24bF0ba1muGS/IGMTWyzfVNzcU@rNiWQZDlr5d5X69FceC8i7PItRHripWLSZDAEKv9FZyoSbZcZ4P@Hc0Ykn0nFbU5apclGabKml0frpVG9Who1yqOmUazHNvsF)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->                      // Method with integer parameter and no return-type
  "    g|EGIJHF|h\n   e]|?ACDB@|^f\n  c[U|9;=><:|V\\d\n aYSO|357864|PTZb\n_WQMK|------|LNRX`"
                         //  String containing the bucket and magic string
   .chars().forEach(c->  //  Loop over the characters (as integers)
     System.out.print(   //   Print:
       c<46|c==124?      //    If the character is "\n", " ", "-", or "|":
        (char)c          //     Output the character as is
       :c<n+51?          //    Else-if the character value is smaller than the input + 51:
        c%10             //     Output a digit: the character value modulo-9
       :                 //    Else:
        " "))            //     Output a space
```

Answer (score 1):

## [6502 machine code](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/6502_Assembly) (C64), 130 bytes

```
00 C0 20 9B B7 A9 C0 65 65 85 FB A2 00 BD 2B C0 F0 1A 10 12 C5 FB 90 04 A9 20
D0 0A 69 70 C9 3A 90 04 E9 0A B0 F8 20 D2 FF E8 D0 E1 60 20 20 20 20 F5 7D D3
D5 D7 D8 D6 D4 7D F6 0D 20 20 20 F3 EB 7D CD CF D1 D2 D0 CE 7D EC F4 0D 20 20
F1 E9 E3 7D C7 C9 CB CC CA C8 7D E4 EA F2 0D 20 EF E7 E1 DD 7D C1 C3 C5 C6 C4
C2 7D DE E2 E8 F0 0D ED E5 DF DB D9 7D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 7D DA DC E0 E6 EE 00
```

This uses a modified version of the "preformatted" approach of some other answers. It contains a full string of the bucket, but the digits are replaced by values starting from `0xC1`, while any characters for direct printing are in the range `0x01`-`0x7f`.

The C64 charset doesn't include a pipe (`|`) character, it's therefore replaced with the similar-looking [PETSCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PETSCII) character `0x7d`.

#### [Online demo](https://vice.janicek.co/c64/#%7B%22controlPort2%22:%22joystick%22,%22primaryControlPort%22:2,%22keys%22:%7B%22SPACE%22:%22%22,%22RETURN%22:%22%22,%22F1%22:%22%22,%22F3%22:%22%22,%22F5%22:%22%22,%22F7%22:%22%22%7D,%22files%22:%7B%22bucket.prg%22:%22data:;base64,AMAgm7epwGVlhfuiAL0rwPAaEBLF+5AEqSDQCmlwyTqQBOkKsPgg0v/o0OFgICAgIPV909XX2NbUffYNICAg8+t9zc/R0tDOfez0DSAg8enjfcfJy8zKyH3k6vINIO/n4d19wcPFxsTCfd7i6PAN7eXf29l9LS0tLS0tfdrc4ObuAA==%22%7D,%22vice%22:%7B%22-autostart%22:%22bucket.prg%22%7D%7D)

Usage: `SYS49152,[n]` (1-indexed, e.g. `SYS49152,54` for the full output)

**Commented disassembly**:

```
         00 C0       .WORD $C000        ; load address
.C:c000  20 9B B7    JSR $B79B          ; get unsigned byte from commandline
.C:c003  A9 C0       LDA #$C0           ; add #$C0 (+ carry = #$C1) ...
.C:c005  65 65       ADC $65            ; ... to parameter
.C:c007  85 FB       STA $FB            ; and store in $FB
.C:c009  A2 00       LDX #$00           ; loop index
.C:c00b   .loop:
.C:c00b  BD 2B C0    LDA .bucket,X      ; loop over encoded string
.C:c00e  F0 1A       BEQ .done          ; null-terminator -> done
.C:c010  10 12       BPL .out           ; positive (bit 7 clear) -> output
.C:c012  C5 FB       CMP $FB            ; compare with parameter+#$C1
.C:c014  90 04       BCC .digit         ; smaller -> convert to digit
.C:c016  A9 20       LDA #$20           ; otherwise load space character
.C:c018  D0 0A       BNE .out           ; and output
.C:c01a   .digit:
.C:c01a  69 70       ADC #$70           ; add offset to '0' (#$30)
.C:c01c   .check:
.C:c01c  C9 3A       CMP #$3A           ; greater than '9' (#$39) ?
.C:c01e  90 04       BCC .out           ; no -> to output
.C:c020  E9 0A       SBC #$0A           ; otherwise subtract 10 (#$a)
.C:c022  B0 F8       BCS .check         ; and check again
.C:c024   .out:
.C:c024  20 D2 FF    JSR $FFD2          ; output character
.C:c027  E8          INX                ; next index
.C:c028  D0 E1       BNE .loop          ; and repeat loop
.C:c02a   .done:
.C:c02a  60          RTS                ; exit ....
.C:c02b   .bucket:
.C:c02b  20 20 20    [...]              ; "encoded" string for bucket
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 64 bytes

```
Ｎθ³↑⁵‖Ｍ←Ｆ²«‖Ｊ⁻³ι±¹Ｆ⊘⁺θ¬ι«↖Ｉ﹪⁺⊗κ⊕ιχＭ§”)⊟E≡≦⌈▷⊖ü∕”κ§”)⊟＆hXτtD(λＭ”κ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3BasMwEETP9leInFaggmzHl/RU2kNd6hBK@wGOvW5FZclRJFMo@XZ3rTSGZdlZ3sy0X41rbaPnuTJj8PswHNHBid@nB6eMh2K9dh@jYCXJN@w1tr5WzlkHu1fsPX176xjknP2myT8A9E1ewjC@W6iVCWcoBFNcsD1@Nh4h4wsQfc@NnrCDgyboRID1oDiPYcnavhQJ9ticPdS2C9pe@ScbjprM35RcmdbhgMaTpgDBMsljS1LbCeHBV6bDH9hIWdymzJe9lXRJuRFsiVm5LJO3KTOZR0Nkr@SSfEkv81xu57tJ/wE) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input the number.

```
³↑⁵‖Ｍ←
```

Draw half of the bucket and then mirror it to complete the bucket.

```
Ｆ²«
```

Loop for each side of the bucket.

```
‖Ｊ⁻³ι±¹
```

Reflect the bucket so that we can draw in a consistent direction on both loops, and jump to the position of the first digit on that side of the bucket.

```
Ｆ⊘⁺θ¬ι«
```

Loop over the number of digits on that side of the bucket.

```
↖Ｉ﹪⁺⊗κ⊕ιχ
```

Print the next digit and move the cursor up and left.

```
Ｍ§”)⊟E≡≦⌈▷⊖ü∕”κ§”)⊟＆hXτtD(λＭ”κ
```

Adjust the cursor position by reading the offsets from two compressed strings, `003003003005203004000500` (horizontal offsets) and `11011011011510200300040000` (vertical offsets). These offsets take the above cursor movement into account which conveniently means that they never have to be negative.